# how to get started with aspects in c#

Tags: c#, aspects

I'v heard about aspects in a programming language and I was pretty enthusiastic about it. However I do not know how to get started with them. And I tought you guys may be set in the right direction.

Comment: use this link: sharpcrafters.com/postsharp. I did it last week and postsharp open my eyes oon AOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# doesn't have an inbuilt facility for this, you need a framework, like PostSharp, to do 'bytecode weaving' (i.e. just writing code to actually make the calls, directly to your classes) to simulate it.

Have a look at the below link where you can find some examples and tutorial

http://www.sharpcrafters.com/

[Aspect Oriented Programming in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416880/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c-sharp)