# Attribute to wrap functions?

Tags: c#, compilation, attributes, word-wrap

I created a class for thread synchronization, that I want to apply to methods, classes, properties etc without going through and inserting my code into every function, class etc. This is an example of the current implementation I have to do:

```
public class NotWhatIWantExample
{
    LockingClass locker;
    public int function()
    {
        locker.EnterWriteBlock();
        if (condition)
        {
            locker.LeaveWriteBlock();
            return 0;
        }
        locker.LeaveWriteBlock();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Next is two examples of what I want to do if possible

Example 2:

```
// [LockingClassAttribute(LockingClassAttribute.WriteBlock)] 
// Not Declared But Added Since Attribute Is Applied On A Method
public class WhatIWantExample
{
    //LockingClass locker; Included In The Attribute

    [LockingClassAttribute(LockingClassAttribute.WriteBlock)]public int function()
    {
        if (condition)
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Example 3:

```
[LockingClassAttribute(LockingClassAttribute.ReadWriteBlock)]
public class WhatIWantExample
{
    //LockingClass locker; Included In The Attribute

    //Function Would Override LockingClassAttribute.ReadWriteBlock
    [LockingClassAttribute(LockingClassAttribute.WriteBlock)]public int function()
    {
        if (condition)
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }
    //Would Inherit [LockingClassAttribute(LockingClassAttribute.ReadWriteBlock)]
    public int function2()
    {
        if (condition)
            return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of [aspect orientated programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). It's not directly available in C#, but you can use [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) to do this sort of thing.

Take a look at the [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/##T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect) class, which allows you to run code before a method is run and after it completes.

Comment: So the PostSharp extension for visual studio would allow this?

Comment: @user3141117 - I've not used the extension, so can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is called `aspect oriented programming`. I have never applied it myself, but there are a few ready-made solutions. See e.g.: [Aspect Oriented Programming in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416880/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c-sharp)