# How to create a [Tag] with specific method call?

Tags: c#, tags, c#-5.0

I'd like to create a new custom "[Tag]" with a particular semantic purpose.

Image you have a list of method in a service and you want some of them to Log some information: actually I'm doing something like

```
public void Method(parameters)
{
   LogMethodCall();

   //Method Body
}
```

Actually I'd prefere to create something like:

```
[LogEnabled]
public void Method(parameters)
{
   //Method Body
}
```

And have somewhere stored something like:

```
if (Method is LogEnabled) LogMethodCall()
```

Is this possible? Exist this possibility in C#? How is it called?

Comment: Never tested it, but you might want to have a look at: http://www.postsharp.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aspect Oriented Programming in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416880/aspect-oriented-programming-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @Dennis How is that a duplicate?

Comment: @svick, the answer leads the user to leverage PostSharp. This is *exactly* what they do.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud But that doesn't make it a duplicate, the two questions are completely different. Or are you saying that all AOP-related questions should be closed as a duplicate of that question (which is now actually closed)?

Comment: @svick, if the solution is exactly the same, how is it not a duplicate? And i'm asking without sarcasm.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Except the solution isn't exactly the same. I don't see anything similar to the code from Adassko's answer in that possible duplicate. And even then, I think questions shouldn't be closed as duplicated based on the *answers*. Only the questions themselves should matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use [postsharp](http://www.postsharp.net):

With it you can create something that is called an `aspect`. Yours will look like:

```
public class LogEnabled : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
        public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            Logger.LogMethodCall();
        }
}
```

Free, express edition will be all you need

And those are called attributes, not "tags"