# Dynamically call method in c#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, dynamic-method

I've got a lot of entity classes, and now in all properties of the entity classes need to add new functionality (call some method) in the getters and setters. What i want to say looks like this:

```
public class PersistentClass : BaseClass {
private string attr1;
[Persistent]
public string Attr1 
{
    get
    {
        //need to call here base class method
        //refreshContents();
        return attr1;
    }
    set
    {
        //need to call here base class method
        //refreshContents();
        attr1 = value;
    }
}

private SomeObject attr2;
[Persistent]
public SomeObject Attr2
{
    get
    {
        //need to call here base class method
        //refreshContents();
        return attr2;
    }
    set
    {
        //need to call here base class method
        //refreshContents();
        attr2 = value;
    }
}

private List<SomeOtherObhect> details;
[Persistent]
pubic List<SomeOtherObject> Details
{
    get
    {
        //need to call here base class method
        //refreshContents("details");
        return details;
    }
    set 
    {
        //need to call here base class method
        //refreshContents("details");
        details = value;
    }
}
```

}

For different types of fields i need to call different methods e.g. `refreshContents()` and `refreshContetns("fieldName")`. I'm looking to solve problem with IoC and Dependency Injection.
Could you help me please?

Comment: you are already doing what you want Achieve. As long as you have a refreshContetns method into the base class it works :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a use case for **Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP)**.

Here are some links to start with:

- [Introduction to Aspect Oriented
  Programming](http://www.jaftalks.com/Home/Show/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-AOP)
- [And some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325558/aspect-oriented-programming-examples)

Comment: i solved the problem with Dynamic Proxy (its part of Castle project)

Answer (score 0):

What will IoC or DI do in your case?

i think you just want a generic method in base class and call thios method from getters or setters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your refresh logic at one place, and call it differently from your properties, consider implementing [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) and handling the PropertyChanged event in your entity class itself and implement the refresh logic there.

However, More important question is why do you want to refresh the contents when a property is set or get? It might help to understand if you provide some real property names.