# Assigning Roles to Application Users

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm, user-roles

As in all the Line-Of-Business Applications, an application may have multiple `Users` with some `Roles` assigned to them. We have recently shifted to WPF MVVM Architecture and looking for best way to assign role to each logged in user. There are many terms floating over internet like Authentication, RoleManager, LoginService etc, but I am not sure which to work out with.

**Here is what we have:**

A small business application (With 20 Forms), developed within a single-project. We use `MVVM` architecture, `LINQ-to-SQL` as DataAccess and `Model`, with `Repository pattern` and `Unit Of Work`.

**What we want:**

There are different forms and each form has *insert*, *update*, *delete*, *print* etc operations. What we want is to restrict a logged in user according to his role - to the task he can perform. i.e for e.g. Admin is free to do "*anything*" with the application, while some other users may not be allowed to view some forms or carry out some operations (viz. update or delete).

So how can we achieve this; what kind of service could be used for carrying out this complete mechanism using MVVM architecture within a Desktop LOB application. A technical term or tutorial link will be helpful.

I hope I am clear and thank you very much in advance.

**Edit:**  I went through many forums and articles around, but all of them focuses on ASP.NET. Still cannot find a concrete implementation for assignment of roles within WPF. And the sources on ASP.NET doesn't comply well with WPF.

Comment: What mvvm framework did you use or did you roll your own?

Comment: We have the same issue. Most of the permissions are hardcoded. We planned to implement full fledged ACL. My colleague offers WCF Roles Service (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386424(v=vs.100).aspx) as ready infrastructure. But we are still not sure about the best way to apply permissions inside viewmodels because we want to avoid hardcoding as much as posible. We also decided to look at Prism. We suspect it to contain the required functionality.

Comment: By the way, have you ever considered using AOP for this task? 
http://izlooite.blogspot.ru/2010/06/aspect-oriented-programming.html
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325558/aspect-oriented-programming-examples
http://www.sharpcrafters.com/

Disclaimer: I'm new to this approach and know almost nothing about it. But Code Contacts are alike so I think it could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest building a solution around the [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) & [Role Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32yf0a9.aspx) providers *(despite the edit to your original question)*. They're well documented on MSDN & are very flexible.

Here are a few links that should hopefully help you with the WPF integration:

- [Can you use the asp.net membership provider in a windows application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444230/can-you-use-the-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-windows-application)
- [WPF Membership API Management Studio](http://wpfmembershipadmin.codeplex.com/)

Also, you mentioned that you're using MVVM; I'd suggest having a static class, or otherwise globally accessible property (see: [WPF Application using a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161459/wpf-application-using-a-global-variable)) of an instance of a centralized authorization class. The methods of this class could then be called from anywhere in the app (i.e. in the ViewModels) to enable/disable or show/hide the appropriate features, based upon whatever permissions were granted to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Microsoft's Security Application block. I have applied it to an application that sounds somewhat similar to yours. Permissions can be stored in Active Directory, SQL or even a flat file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664771(v=pandp.50).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664559(v=pandp.50).aspx

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create a static class in the client layer containing information of the current user (roles, permissions, etc). These permissions could be modeled for example by an enum or something like that, then in each ViewModel you can define which of these enum values is required for example to perform queries (view the records) or execute the Save or Edit Commands.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply put a RequiredRole property in each command and add an override of CanExecute that checks the current user has the right to do it. This is enough for commands.

On the other hand, rights to display a form must be checked in your screen conductor/tab host/...

Fetch the roles and each suer role with Linq to Sql, and it's over. I would not bother with integrating external code for such a simple task.

If you want to make it more generic, keep in your DB a table linking commands/forms and roles, and use reflection to authorize users.

I hope you will find that useful

Answer (score 0):

We're using AD to determine the roles a user belongs to. Then checking that any of the roles has the right permission. However you could use a `roles` and `userroles` table to do this part yourself.

Using either of those two approaches the user will be in a set of roles. That's the first step.

Then you need to verify at the point of action that the user has permission.
Our menu structure is dynamically built up from the database, so I have a table of `MenuItems` and then a table defining `RoleMenuAvailability`.

The first has an `Id`, an `order`, the `Title`, `Image source` and the `navigation target`, along with a few other fields.

The second has the `RoleId` and the `menuId` and whether it is editable.
So the presence of the row means its readable (if a navigation target ie form)
The menu items are then read in from the database:

```cs
var usersItems =
    items.Where(i => i.RoleMenuAvailabilities
                    .Any(r => domainUser.IsInDomainRole(r.UserRole.Description)))
         .OrderBy(m => m.MenuOrder);
```

`UserRole.Description` in our case is the name of the AD role, and `IsInDomainRole` is a helper function:

```cs
public bool IsInDomainRole(string role)
{
    var regex = new Regex("[^\\\\]+$");
    string name = this.Name ?? string.Empty;
    string domainRole = regex.Replace(name, role);
    return this.IsInRole(domainRole);
}
```

The `rolemenuavailability` table could be extended to have additional flags on it for delete, update, add etc if you required.

We haven't fully implemented the next stages, but the intention is that we will have the user permissions cached against the user. Our ViewModel base class has a reference to the user and can thus Call the `CanEdit(int permissionId)` function. Then the properties that essentially control the visibility or the Commands `CanExecute` can thus access the user permissions and find out if they have the permission for whatever the action is.

It's still a work in progress so will be interested to see what other suggestions come up here.